# Filtering a table by using vue multiselect

Tags: javascript, vue.js, multi-select, vue-multiselect

I'm trying to filter the results of a table by using vue-multiselect. I can see the **selected** values in the VUE dev tools as a part of multiselect component. How do I **use** these values to be used in `filter()` function to get the filtered table results.

Below you can see my JS script implementation and Template multiselect implementation as well.

**JS Script**

```
export default {
  data: () => ({
    policies: [],
    selectedValues: [],
    options: [],
  }),

  methods: {
    filterByStatus: function({ label, value }) {
    return this.policies.filter(data => {
        let status= data.status.toLowerCase().match(this.selectedValues.toLowerCase());
  },
```

**Template**

```
 <multiselect
          v-model="selectedValues"
          :options="options"
          :multiple="true"
          label="label"
          track-by="label"
          placeholder="Filter by status"
          @select="filterByStatus"
        ></multiselect>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your select component is using the prop `:multiple="true"`, this means the bound value `selectedValues`, with `v-model`, will return an array of policy objects.

Instead of using a `filterByStatus` function in the methods component options, create two computed properties.

One that computes an array of the selected policies statuses and another one that computes the filtered array of policies you want to display.

Script:

```
computed: {
  selectedStatuses() {
    const statuses = []
    for (const { status } of this.selectedValues) {
      statuses.push(status.toLowerCase())
    }
    return statuses
  },
  filteredPolicies() {
    if (this.selectedStatuses.length === 0) {
      return this.policies
    }
    const policies = []
    for (const policy of this.policies) {
      if (this.selectedStatuses.includes(policy.status.toLowerCase())) {
        policies.push(policy)
      }
    }
    return policies
  }
}
```

Template:

```
<multiselect
          v-model="selectedValues"
          :options="options"
          :multiple="true"
          label="label"
          track-by="label"
          placeholder="Filter by status"
        ></multiselect>
```

Example:

```js
Vue.config.productionTip = Vue.config.devtools = false

new Vue({
  name: 'App',

  components: {
    Multiselect: window.VueMultiselect.default
  },

  data() {
    return {
      policies: [{
        label: 'Policy A',
        status: 'enabled'
      }, {
        label: 'Policy B',
        status: 'disabled'
      }, {
        label: 'Policy C',
        status: 'Deprecated'
      }],
      selectedValues: [],
      options: [{
        label: 'Enabled',
        status: 'enabled'
      }, {
        label: 'Disabled',
        status: 'DISABLED'
      }, {
        label: 'Deprecated',
        status: 'DePrEcAtEd'
      }]
    }
  },

  computed: {
    selectedStatuses() {
      const statuses = []
      for (const {
          status
        } of this.selectedValues) {
        statuses.push(status.toLowerCase())
      }
      return statuses
    },
    filteredPolicies() {
      if (this.selectedStatuses.length === 0) {
        return this.policies
      }
      const policies = []
      for (const policy of this.policies) {
        if (this.selectedStatuses.includes(policy.status.toLowerCase())) {
          policies.push(policy)
        }
      }
      return policies
    }
  },
}).$mount('#app')
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue-multiselect@2.1.0"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/vue-multiselect@2.1.0/dist/vue-multiselect.min.css">

<div id="app">
  <multiselect v-model="selectedValues" :options="options" :multiple="true" label="label" track-by="label" placeholder="Filter by status"></multiselect>
  <pre>Policies: {{ filteredPolicies}}</pre>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is better to keep the filter function inside `computed`.

```
computed:{
      filterByStatus: function ({label, value}) {
          return this.policies.filter((data) => {
              return data.status && data.status.toLowerCase().includes(this.selectedValues.toLowerCase())
          });
      }
}
```

Using the `filterByStatus` in the template section will render the result in real time.

```
<div>{{filterByStatus}}</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use watch on selectedValues when any change or selection :

```
watch:{
selectedValues: function(value){
this.policies.filter(data => {
        let status= data.status.toLowerCase().match(this.selectedValues.toLowerCase());

}


}
```

Answer (score 0):

This how I did in one of my vue3 projects, where I had multiple dropdowns with multi-items can be selected to filter and with a text input box:

```
const filterByInput = (item: string) =>
    item.toLowerCase().includes(state.searchInput.toLowerCase());

const filteredItems = computed(() => {
  let fItems = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(props.items));

  if (state.searchInput) {
    fItems = fItems.filter((item) => filterByInput(item.title));
  }

  if (state.filterByState.length) {
    fItems = fItems.filter((item) => state.filterByState.includes(item.state));
  }

  if (state.filterByType.length) {
    fItems = fItems.filter((item) => state.filterByType.includes(item.typeId));
  }

  if (state.filterByPublishing !== null) {
    fItems = fItems.filter((item) => item.published === state.filterByPublishing);
  }

  return fItems;

  // NOTE: other options that you can try (should be placed above `return`)
  // const filterMultiSelect = (fItems, selectedItems, key) => {
  //   // OPT-1: foreach
  //   const arr = [];
  //   fItems.forEach((item) => {
  //     if (selectedItems.includes(item[key])) {
  //       arr.push(item);
  //     }
  //   });
  //   return arr;

  //   // OPT-2: filter
  //   return fItems.filter((item) => selectedItems.includes(item[key]));
  // };

  // if (state.filterByState.length) {
  //   fItems = filterMultiSelect(fItems, state.filterByType, 'typeId');
  // }

});
```

You can find full code in this [gist](https://gist.github.com/syed-haroon/5006360e7f827229277c31a86c9fc5a7)